# Where to send message to smartwatch? ViewModel, UseCase or Repository?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-architecture-components

Where should I place/split the following code?

The ViewModel shouldn't be responsible for business logic, but I also don't know how to handle the  UseCases, have two 'special' UseCases for updating the Ip and the object, which then depend on a general UseCase (SendDataToWatch) to actually send the data? In that case, where should I get the Nodes list and decide to which node to send the message, in ViewModel?

Or should I pass the context to the Repository, but then, which one? (ConnectionDataRep, CmdObjectsRep or one created for this purpose).

Also, regarding the ThreadExecutor, since it is expensive to create, should I pass it from the ViewModel, or create it in each UseCase/Repository?

```
private Collection<String> getNodes() {
    HashSet<String> results = new HashSet<>();
    Wearable.getCapabilityClient()
    Task<CapabilityInfo> nodeListTask = Wearable.getCapabilityClient(context).getCapability(WATCH_CAPABILITY, CapabilityClient.FILTER_REACHABLE);

    try {
        // Block on a task and get the result synchronously (because this is on a background
        // thread).
        Set<Node> nodes = Tasks.await(nodeListTask).getNodes();

        for (Node node : nodes) {
            results.add(node.getId());
        }

    } catch (ExecutionException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Task failed: " + exception);

    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Interrupt occurred: " + exception);
    }

    return results;
}

private void updateAddrOnWatch(String node, String message) {
    sendMessageToEndpoint(node, KeysConstants.UPDATE_CONN_PATH, strToBytes(message));
}

private void updateCmdObjects(String node, String jsonObjectsArr) {
    sendMessageToEndpoint(node, KeysConstants.UPDATE_OBJECTS_PATH, strToBytes(jsonObjectsArr));
}

private void sendMessageToEndpoint(String node, String endpoint, byte[] message) {
    Task<Integer> sendMessageTask =
            Wearable.getMessageClient(context)
                    .sendMessage(node, endpoint, message);

    try {
        // Block on a task and get the result synchronously (because this is on a background
        // thread).
        Integer result = Tasks.await(sendMessageTask);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message sent: " + result);

    } catch (ExecutionException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Task failed: " + exception);

    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Interrupt occurred: " + exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: ViewModel is tied to to some screens, I'd probably have ViewModel own the lifecycle of some Repository that exposes the methods and some StateFlow for available devices etc.

Comment: In the end I used a Service which still has context information and runs communication with the smartwatch on a background thread, and it can also be used from different Activities.